# Script .Sh is not running in Windows?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to **run .Sh file on my Windows machine** using **GitBash** but it is giving error -

```
run_main.sh: line 3: pkill: command not found
rm: cannot remove '/root/impactAllClient/NewsCollected.csv': No such file or directory
run_main.sh: line 7: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3binpythonimpactAllClient-mastercreateDataset.py: command not found
run_main.sh: line 10: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3binpythonimpactAllClient-masterallClientAbstractive.py: command not found
```

Though I have my files in correct locations - `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin\python\impactAllClient-master`

**Here is my .sh File code**

```
    #!/bin/bash

pkill -f allClientAbstractive.py
sleep 10
rm /root/impactAllClient/NewsCollected.csv

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin\python\impactAllClient-master\createDataset.py
sleep 10

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin\python\impactAllClient-master\allClientAbstractive.py &
```

Comment: Only one question at a time, please. Not having `pkill` is one question (though it's not necessarily on-topic here; the answer comes down to "yes, that's right, you don't have pkill unless you install it" -- it's not part of bash itself but a separate tool). Your Python scripts resulting in "command not found" is a separate question, and tracking down why requires information you haven't included here (what the shebang line is for those scripts, f/e).

Answer (score 0):

Can you run `pkill` manually in GitBash? I guess it's not installed.

I think this is not a valid Windows path: `/root/impactAllClient/NewsCollected.csv`. It should start with something like `/c/...`.

Also the Paths `C:\ProgramData\...`, should use forward slashes and start like  `/c/ProgrammData/...`, when using GitBash.

You can open a bash shell in the path `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin\python\impactAllClient-master\` and then run `pwd`. The path that is printed to the console should be used in the script.

Comment: yes pkill is not installed what is the package for pkill in windows any idea ? @schilli